# CSS transition doesn't work in FF when add overflow hidden on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

I have some problem with overflow hidden and CSS transitions. The transition animation works fine until code is added to set `overflow: hidden` on the `<body>` element. If that happens, the transition animation does not work; the element just changes immediately.

Look this example, please: http://jsfiddle.net/Lg3q911b/2/

CSS:

```
#block {
    background: red;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 203px;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    transform: translate3d(-203px, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}

#block.is-opened {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="block"></div>
<a href="#" id="toggle">Toggle</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggle').on('click', function() {
       $('#block').addClass('is-opened');
        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    });
});
```

If the line that adds the `overflow` setting to the `<body>` is commented out, the animation works.

Maybe somebody know, how to fix it?

Comment: that's pretty weird.

Comment: Thats weird you ought to explain whats your problem just and code and fiddle make no sense

Comment: If you put the `overflow` rule in the stylesheet (always setting the `<body>` to `overflow: hidden`) then it works, but I don't know why the posted code doesn't work.

Comment: @Pointy yes, I know, tha it is works, but I need 'overflow hidden' only when red square is visible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug, which has already been fixed for upcoming versions.

I can reproduce your problem using Firefox 32.

However, on Firefox Nightly 35, it works well.

Comment: I have broke my brain, trying fixing this) Thank you!